# Directly importing header file in python code

Tags: c++, python-2.7, cython

Can a calcBeta.h (header file) ,having C++ function defined in itself, be directly imported to a python file as

```
cdef extern from "calcBeta.h":
```

without doing a setup.py compilation with a .cpp file ?Since the function is completely defined in the header ,it can be directly called from there in a python code via importing it and thus no need for a .cpp file.

Please let me know if my understanding is correct or it is mandatoryto have  Cython compilation of .pyx & .cpp file

Comment: I don't know of a way to directly import a header file. Have you checked out Boost Python http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html? While it isn't as simple as importing a header file it is a lot less hairy than the Python/C++ API

Answer (score 0):

When you define an import like

```
cdef extern from "calcBeta.h":
```

you need to **exactly specify what's contained in that import**, or Cython will be annoyed.
So you'd need to write:

```
cdef extern from "calcBeta.h":
    int someFunctionIWantToBindTo(int foo, char* bar)
```

because Cython can't parse the header file and figure out what you want to do with it on its own.